# Onclick event not working. Can someone show me how to properly debug please?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, onclick

I'm getting this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: toFahrenheit is not defined
at HTMLInputElement.onclick
I am looking for the reason why, but much more importantly, what is the process I should take when trying to fix the code? 
In the end there should be text at the end of the HTML using the DOM connected to the functions.

```js
// Each function should correspond with an on-click event 
// but when I press the buttons nothing happens

function toCelsius() {

 var celsius = (document.getElementById("userInput").value - 32) * 5 / 9;
 celsius = Math.round(celsius);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTMl = userInput.value + " Farenheit is " + celsius + "Celsius";
}

function toFahrenheit() {

 var fahrenheit = (document.getElementById("userInput").value * 9 / 5 + 32;
 fahrenheit = Math.round(fahrenheit);
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTMl = userInput.value + " Celsius is " +
     celsius + "Fahrenheit";
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="userInput">Enter your number to convert: </label>
    <input type="number" id="userInput">
 </div>
               
 <div class="form-group">
  <input type="button" value="To Celsius" onclick="toCelsius();">
   <input type="button" value="To Fahrenheit" onclick="toFahrenheit();">
  </div>
</form>

<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: what did you see in your console ?

Comment: Where did you put your javascript ?

Comment: `userInput.value` what is this ? maybe you meant `document.getElementById("userInput").value` .. and you are missing a `)`

Comment: Step 1: LINT !! Step 2: try and observe Step 3: fix

Comment: Syntax error in your code halts code execution: `(document.getElementById("userInput").value * 9 / 5 + 32;` --> no closing parenthesis. Same for celsius. Voting to close, simple typo.

Comment: That's why we have developers tools nowadays. While in your browser hit F12 on your keyboard and look around.

Comment: Make sure you have put your javascript in the script tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first thing, you are missing the closing parenthesis on the two math lines:

```
(document.getElementById("userInput").value * 9 / 5 + 32;
```

You also have a typo with the two lines that start off with:

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTMl = ...
```

because JavaScript is case-sensitive and it should be:

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = ...
```

These alone are enough to cause your code to stop working and you would have been alerted to these issues if you ran your code with your browser's developer tools turned on (press F12 in any modern browser) and click to the `Console` tab. This is where most JavaScript errors will be reported. It will even display the line number where the error is and if you click that link, it will take you straight to it:

[image]

Moving on, you shouldn't use the `form` element if you are not going to gather up the form element values and submit them anywhere.

Next up, don't use inline HTML event attributes, such as `onclick`, there are many reasons why and you can read about them **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991)**. Do all your event binding in JavaScript using **[modern standards](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)**.

Also, there's no need for two separate functions here since they both do just about the same thing. If each button stored the unit it was meant to convert to, that unit could be passed to a single function that would use it to determine the proper math to do. We can make that happen by using the HTML **[`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*)** attribute and then pick up that value in JavaScript with the **[`.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)** property.

Lastly, remember that the "T" in "HTML" stands for "text". All data gotten from an HTML element is always a string to JavaScript. If you want to do math with it, you need to convert it to a number. This can be done in many ways, but pre-pending a `+` operator to the string will do it.

```js
// Get both buttons into a JavaScript array and loop over them
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("input[type='button']")).forEach(function(btn){
    // Set up a common event handler for each that gets the "data-unit" HTML attribute value
    // and passes it to the function
    btn.addEventListener("click", function(){ convert(this.dataset.unit) 
  });
});

// Get references to the elements you'll need to work with
var input = document.getElementById("userInput");
var output = document.getElementById("result");

// Single click callback function that recieves the unit based on the button clicked
function convert(unit) {
  var other = null;    // Will hold unit we are converting to
  var answer = null;   // Will hold answer
  
  // Check the passed in argument value to see which math we need to do
  if(unit.toLowerCase() === "celsius"){
    other = "Fahrenheit"
    answer = (+input.value - 32) * 5 / 9;
  } else {
    other = "Celsius";
    answer = (+input.value * 9 / 5) + 32;
  }
  answer = Math.round(answer);
  
  // Write out result:
  output.textContent = input.value + " degrees " + other + " is: " + answer + " degrees " + unit;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="userInput">Enter your number to convert: </label>
  <input type="number" id="userInput">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <input type="button" id="btnC" data-unit="Celsius" value="To Celsius">
  <input type="button" id="btnF" data-unit="Fahrenheit" value="To Fahrenheit">
</div>

<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: nicely explained lot to learn from your answer how to write a answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try following use browser console to debug JavaScript

```js
function toCelsius() {

  var celsius = (document.getElementById("userInput").value - 32) * 5 / 9;

  celsius = Math.round(celsius);



  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = userInput.value + " Fahrenheit is    " + celsius + " Celsius ";
}

function toFahrenheit() {

  var fahrenheit = (document.getElementById("userInput").value) * (9 / 5) + 32;

  fahrenheit = Math.round(fahrenheit);

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = userInput.value + " Celsius is    " + fahrenheit + " Fahrenheit ";
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">

  <label for="userInput">Enter your number to convert: </label>
  <input type="number" id="userInput">

</div>


<div class="form-group">

  <input type="button" value="To Celsius" onclick="toCelsius()">
  <input type="button" value="To Fahrenheit" onclick="toFahrenheit()">

</div>

<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: For this I just place your code in codepen it will show you where is the error you can also use browser console.https://codepen.io/nisalsp9/pen/NwxbQv

Comment: You don't even need a code pen. You can see it right here in a code snippet.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Agreed I said that I did